# Proof that $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) = \{\text{all linear transformations}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the basis we have for saying that the set of homomorphisms from vector spaces $V$ to $W$ is the set of linear transformations from $V$ to $W$?  Is there a standard proof to show that the set of functions which map $V$ to $W$ such that $W$ is still a vector space (i.e. such that the vector space "structure" is preserved) is exactly the of linear functions from $V$ to $W$?

I might be able to prove this myself if I could figure out exactly what "preserving the VS structure" means.  As it stands, it is too vague to me for me to see how to test for it.

Comment: preserving the vector space structure means that your function is linear

Comment: A homomorphism of vector spaces over a field $F$ is an $F$-linear map by definition. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: Why don't you write down the definition of vector space homomorphism and linear transformation? If you write it down, you will automatically find your answer.

Comment: My question is really more like why we define a VS homomorphism to be a linear transformation, given the more general notion of a homomorphism.  I think I've got it figured out though.  A function which preserves the VS structure should preserve the two operations which *define* a VS.  That is, for some homomorphism $f$, we should have $f(av) = af(v)$ and $f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w)$.  But that exactly means that $f$ is linear.

Comment: @user275324 That is absolutely correct.